# How to access different components by routes with slug only in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Lets say we have two components for Post and Project. Each post and project has slug. I want to access post and projects by slug. So we have routes:

```
<Route path="/:post_slug" component={PostComponent} />
<Route path="/:project_slug" component={ProjectComponent} />
```

And for example when you visit some post pr project, an action gets called to fetch its data by params. Something like this:

```
this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.post_slug)
this.props.fetchProject(this.props.match.params.project_slug)
```

If I do only one component accessible by slug only, then it works. But if I want to access two different components by slug, then it's messed up. And i.e. when I visit post, react thinks that I'm visiting project.

Maybe there is some way to handle such case in react-router-dom?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to do this, since the router can't differentiate between the two routes. For example, if I were to navigate to `site.com/my_slug`, the router wouldn't know whether `my_slug` is supposed to be a `:post_slug` or a `:project_slug`. It's sending you to a project when they're both present because it interprets them to be the same route and so it uses the last one you define.

An alternative you could try is being a bit more explicit with your routes, like so:

```
<Route path="/post/:post_slug"       component={PostComponent} />
<Route path="/project/:project_slug" component={ProjectComponent} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your asnwer. Yes, I agree with more explicit routes. But still trying to make it work. If I wrap my root component with `withRouter`, then I get info about my params in `this.props.match`. I'll try to make some sort of a handler to check what slug is passed.

Comment: @Dair, you should accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this if you put the detection logic in another component, like this:

```
<Route path="/:any_slug" component={AnyComponent} />
```

Then let that component figure out what type of ID you have and render the desired sub-component accordingly:

```
const AnyComponent = props => {
    if (slugIsProject(props.match.params.any_slug)) {
        return <ProjectComponent id={props.match.params.any_slug} />;
    } else {
        return <PostComponent id={props.match.params.any_slug} />;
    }
}
```

This way the router always renders the same component (`AnyComponent`) but that component appears differently depending on what the ID is determined to be.